# Can be kubernetes storage class parameters modified on the fly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, storage-class-specifier

We have a gp3 storage class that is the default one in our Kubernetes cluster (EKS). But the EBS volumes that are attached to our PV have the default IOPS and we want to change the default IOPS value, we want to increase it.

We have a 1.21 Kubernetes version.

And we have the following terraform code on how we manage the storage classes in our kubernetes cluster:

```
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "aws-ebs-csi-gp3-storage-class" {
  metadata {
    name = "aws-ebs-csi-gp3"
    annotations = {
      "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class" = "true"
    }
  }

  storage_provisioner    = "ebs.csi.aws.com"
  reclaim_policy         = "Delete"
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  volume_binding_mode    = "Immediate"
}
```

We want to change the above code with the following one:

```
resource "kubernetes_storage_class" "aws-ebs-csi-gp3-storage-class" {
  metadata {
    name = "aws-ebs-csi-gp3"
    annotations = {
      "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class" = "true"
    }
  }

  storage_provisioner    = "ebs.csi.aws.com"
  reclaim_policy         = "Delete"
  allow_volume_expansion = true
  volume_binding_mode    = "Immediate"
  parameters             = {
    type: gp3
    iopsPerGB: "10"
  }
}
```

Does this modification affect all the PVs that are assigned to that storage class?
It does recreate them, how does this change affect the stateful sets that are using those PVs?

Thank you,
-Ionut